# WPFMediaKit:VideoCaptureElement is streaming the video in alternate windows in WPF

Tags: wpf

XAML:

```
<WPFMediaKit:VideoCaptureElement 
      LoadedBehavior="Play" 
      StretchDirection="Both" 
      FPS="30" 
      Stretch="Uniform" 
      VideoCaptureSource="{Binding Path=CaptureDeviceName}"
      UnloadedBehavior="Stop" 
      EnableSampleGrabbing="true"
      DesiredPixelWidth="1280" 
      DesiredPixelHeight="1024"
      Width="Auto" 
      Height="Auto" 
      x:Name="videoCapElement" 
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

UserControl.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    DsDevice dev1 = MultimediaUtil.VideoInputDevices.FirstOrDefault();
    DsDevice dev2 = MultimediaUtil.VideoInputDevices.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        try
        {
            if (dev1 != null)
            {
                videoCapElement.VideoCaptureDevice = dev1;
                videoCapElement.VideoCaptureSource = dev1.Name;
            }  
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

With the above code in place , when I am referring the user control in Multiple Window.xaml files and Navigating from one window to the other window, I am getting the video streaming in alternate windows.

Comment: <WPFMediaKit:VideoCaptureElement  LoadedBehavior="Play"  StretchDirection="Both" FPS="30"  Stretch="Uniform"  VideoCaptureSource="{Binding Path=CaptureDeviceName}"   UnloadedBehavior="Stop"     EnableSampleGrabbing="true"
 DesiredPixelWidth="1280" DesiredPixelHeight="1024"
 Width="Auto" Height="Auto" x:Name="videoCapElement" 
  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
    </WPFMediaKit:VideoCaptureElement>

Comment: The above is my UserControl.xaml

Answer (score 1):

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    DsDevice dev1 = null;

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        videoCapElement.Stop();
        dev1 = MultimediaUtil.VideoInputDevices.FirstOrDefault();
        try
        {

            if (dev1 != null)
            {

                videoCapElement.VideoCaptureDevice = dev1;
                videoCapElement.VideoCaptureSource = dev1.Name;
                videoCapElement.Play();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stop the video from playing when ever you Navigate from one Window to another Window